# Api facebook i can't get all information

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I would get email with my application facebook

I have this code javascript in my page login.php

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '277408952302897',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : 'localhost/pub/', // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true,                                // Look for social plugins on the page
      oauth: true

    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

   jQuery(function($)
   {
       $('.facebookConnect').click(function()
       {
           var url=$(this).attr('href');
           FB.login(function(response)
           {
               if(response.authResponse)
               {
                    window.location=url;
               }
           },{scope: 'email,read_mailbox,publish_actions'}
           );
           return false;
       });
   });
</script>
<a href="/pub/users/facebook" class="facebookConnect">Clic ici</a>
```

I accept application with my account facebook

and i have this code in my page facebook.php

```
include '../webroot/fb/facebook.php';
        //Get Facebook SDK Object
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => '277408952302897',
          'secret' => 'secret',
        ));
        $user = $facebook->getUser();
        debug($user);
        die("koko");
```

I have have this in my screen `(int) 0 koko`

Comment: are you sure you need this line `oauth: true` ?

Comment: sincerely no but Even if I remove anything hapend: s

Comment: You are not making _any_ API call to get the email or any other info.

Comment: I get the email with this code {scope: 'email,read_mailbox,publish_actions'}

Comment: The user being 0 just means they are not currently logged in via your site. Cant you generate a loginUrl in PHP to use in the front end rather than using both the PHP and JavaScript SDKs?

Comment: Setting the scope doesn’t _get_ you any data from the API, it just sets the permissions to ask for on login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add this in you configuration

```
FB.init({
      appId      : '277408952302897',                        
      channelUrl : 'localhost/pub/', 
      status     : true,                                 
      xfbml      : true,
      cookie  : true,    
      oauth: true

    });
```